# Polar form for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{C})$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have some doubts in measure theory. Suppose $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{C})$, then $f=f_1+if_2$, where $f_1,~f_2\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R})$. Is it possible to write this function in a polar form: $\sqrt{f_1^2+f_2^2}exp(iS(x))$, where $S(x)$ is the principal value of $tan^{-1}\left(\frac{f_2(x)}{f_1(x)}\right)$? I am confused since $f$ is an equivalence class of functions and I cannot seem to justify doing this calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to calculate with equivalence classes is:

1. Pick a arbitrary element from each class (a *representative*)
2. Perform the calculation
3. Prove that the equivalence class in which the result lies is independent of the choices in 1.

In this situation:

1. Pick a representative of $f$.
2. For each $x\in\mathbb R^n$ the complex number $f(x)$ can be written in the form $r e^{i\theta}$ so that $r\ge 0$, $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, and if $r=0$, then also $\theta=0$. This set of conditions makes $r$ and $\theta$ unambiguously determined by $f(x)$. Thus we have $r$ and $\theta$ as functions of $x$.
3. Now suppose I picked a different representative $\tilde f$ and obtained $\tilde r$ and $\tilde \theta$ as above. Then $r=\tilde r$ and $\theta=\tilde \theta$ almost everywhere, because $f=\tilde f$  almost everywhere. Hence, the equivalence classes of $r$ and of $\theta$ are independent of the choice of $f$.

---

The above does not yet show that $r$ and $\theta$ are measurable, but this is not hard to do. For example, the set where $\theta\in (\alpha,\beta)$   is the preimage of a certain Borel set under $f$, and therefore is measurable.